# How to auto-generate R code for recreating sf object?

Tags: r, sf

What package/function can one use to generate code for recreating an existing `sf` object? I am trying to make my first reprex, which is for a different question, but am having a hard time recreating the specific `sf` object that I am working with (which is necessary for my specific question). There are plenty of general guides on writing reprexes (such as [here](https://reprex.tidyverse.org/articles/learn-reprex.html) and [here](https://community.rstudio.com/t/faq-whats-a-reproducible-example-reprex-and-how-do-i-create-one/5219)), but these do not seem to fully apply to `sf`.

For my particular case, I have come up with the code below. It converts the `sfc` of an `sf` object (`LINESTRING`) to a plain dataframe and then passes the result to `datapasta::dpasta`, which puts code in the script for creating the dataframe object. The problem with this output code is that it does not seem ready for conversion to an `sf`-style object, as I keep getting errors when trying to make a `LINESTRING` out of the list. This approach feels adhoc and overly manual, so I am hoping that there exists a more general alternative for this kind of situation.

```
x <- data.frame(bline$geometry) # geometry column of an sf object with one LINESTRING

datapasta::dpasta(x)

## dpasta pastes the following code into the script

data.frame(
                     geometry = c("c(-792285.491251808, -792285.488817639, -792285.436522982, -792285.384427687, -792285.33267453, -792285.281405349, -792285.230760659, -792285.180879259, -792285.13189786, -792285.083950704, -792285.037169198, -792284.991681557, -790240.702683605, -790240.659579577, -750536.528415538, -743907.032905619, -743907.021055776, -705997.347638523, -704336.097999047, -704336.060652765, -664913.220854293, -659976.689106017, -659976.677471231, -640303.816873962, -640303.813512255, -620718.901662572, -616828.918835104, 
-610882.403771673, -610882.394685652, -595564.578577553, -578300.598930178, -576658.107865964, -576658.074277915, -537693.254220241, -534429.766727421, -534429.748408387, -518012.54009363, -485910.696784914, -485910.691773335, -452102.325903294, -448880.542010921, -448880.520954105, -442063.307672312, -442063.266728173, -442063.227500371, -442063.190094792, -442063.154612405, -442063.121148988, -442063.089794869, -442063.060634682, -442063.033747138, -442063.009204815, -442062.98707396, -442062.96741431, 
-442062.950278934, -442062.935714084, -442062.923759075, -442062.914446178, -442062.90780053, -442062.90384007, -442062.902575489, -442062.9040102, -442062.90814033, -442062.914954731, -442062.924435009, -442062.936555573, -442062.951283708, -442062.968579657, -442062.988396733, -442063.010681444, -442063.035373637, -442063.062406661, -442063.091707545, -442063.096064972, 2918748.30210906, 2918748.30212301, 2918748.2996829, 2918748.29450937, 2918748.28661659, 2918748.2760262, 2918748.26276722, 2918748.24687599, 
2918748.22839606, 2918748.20737808, 2918748.18387966, 2918748.15796519, 2917511.54289283, 2917511.51528765, 2890626.4525922, 2886229.1088279, 2886229.10084542, 2860296.14740504, 2859255.91763225, 2859255.89306825, 2832044.60830091, 2828717.72270611, 2828717.71474522, 2815052.34456301, 2815052.34221764, 2801328.70929097, 2798649.81543859, 2794555.39323204, 2794555.38690149, 2783756.45528285, 2771592.78589961, 2770523.36937069, 2770523.34651698, 2742836.82623387, 2740608.56736203, 2740608.55455154, 
2728852.61822133, 2705882.11145883, 2705882.10784934, 2681373.37633357, 2679115.88414793, 2679115.86898237, 2674070.35896075, 2674070.32697836, 2674070.29291262, 2674070.25685546, 2674070.21890423, 2674070.17916136, 2674070.13773414, 2674070.09473438, 2674070.05027816, 2674070.00448547, 2674069.95747993, 2674069.90938842, 2674069.86034074, 2674069.8104693, 2674069.75990871, 2674069.70879544, 2674069.65726748, 2674069.6054639, 2674069.55352455, 2674069.50158962, 2674069.44979929, 2674069.39829337, 
2674069.34721089, 2674069.29668973, 2674069.24686627, 2674069.19787498, 2674069.14984812, 2674069.10291533, 2674069.05720328, 2674069.01283537, 2674068.96993136, 2674068.96421305)",
                 NA)
)

## Errors I get when subsequently running the code below
sf::st_linestring(x = as.numeric(x$geometry)) # Error in stopifnot(is.numeric(x), is.matrix(x), !anyNA(x)) : 'list' object cannot be coerced to type 'double'

sf::st_linestring(x = as.numeric(unlist(x$geometry))) # Error in valid_numeric_matrix(x) : is.matrix(x) is not TRUE
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you may be looking for `base::dput`.

To see it in action consider the following code; it takes the geometry of the well known & much liked `nc.shp` shapefile that ships with {sf}, and is itself a nice idea for reprexes, puts it out in text format on console; the output is then pasted back to a machine format.

```r
library(sf)

# the one & only NC shapefile... as geometry only
shape <- st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf")) 

# county Ashe geometry
cnty_ashe <- shape[1, ]$geometry

# to console, unless specified otherwise...
dput(cnty_ashe)

# a check to make sure
my_data <- structure(list(structure(list(list(structure(c(-81.4727554321289, 
                                                            -81.5408401489258, -81.5619812011719, -81.6330642700195, -81.7410736083984, 
                                                            -81.6982803344727, -81.7027969360352, -81.6699981689453, -81.3452987670898, 
                                                            -81.347541809082, -81.3247756958008, -81.3133239746094, -81.2662353515625, 
                                                            -81.2628402709961, -81.2406921386719, -81.2398910522461, -81.2642440795898, 
                                                            -81.3289947509766, -81.3613739013672, -81.3656921386719, -81.354133605957, 
                                                            -81.3674545288086, -81.4063873291016, -81.4123306274414, -81.431037902832, 
                                                            -81.4528884887695, -81.4727554321289, 36.2343559265137, 36.2725067138672, 
                                                            36.2735939025879, 36.3406867980957, 36.3917846679688, 36.4717788696289, 
                                                            36.5193405151367, 36.5896492004395, 36.5728645324707, 36.537914276123, 
                                                            36.5136795043945, 36.4806976318359, 36.4372062683105, 36.4050407409668, 
                                                            36.3794174194336, 36.365364074707, 36.3524131774902, 36.3635025024414, 
                                                            36.3531608581543, 36.3390502929688, 36.2997169494629, 36.2786979675293, 
                                                            36.2850532531738, 36.2672920227051, 36.2607192993164, 36.2395858764648, 
                                                            36.2343559265137), dim = c(27L, 2L)))), class = c("XY", "MULTIPOLYGON", 
                                                                                                              "sfg"))), class = c("sfc_MULTIPOLYGON", "sfc"), precision = 0, bbox = structure(c(xmin = -81.7410736083984, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                ymin = 36.2343559265137, xmax = -81.2398910522461, ymax = 36.5896492004395
                                                                                                              ), class = "bbox"), crs = structure(list(input = "NAD27", wkt = "GEOGCRS[\"NAD27\",\n    DATUM[\"North American Datum 1927\",\n        ELLIPSOID[\"Clarke 1866\",6378206.4,294.978698213898,\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1]]],\n    PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0,\n        ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433]],\n    CS[ellipsoidal,2],\n        AXIS[\"latitude\",north,\n            ORDER[1],\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433]],\n        AXIS[\"longitude\",east,\n            ORDER[2],\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433]],\n    ID[\"EPSG\",4267]]"), class = "crs"), n_empty = 0L)
```

Comment: This simple approach is exactly what was needed, thanks!